# calculation with $index in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to do some arithmetic operation with `$index` in `ng-repeat`. 
The following code is not working:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in quotation.items track by $index">
    <td class="text-center"><strong>{{$index++}}</strong></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);">{{item.item}}</a></td>
    <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
    <td>{{item.rate}}</td>
    <td>{{item.rate * item.quantity}}</td>
</tr>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I have a feeling you need `$index + 1`, as `$index++` tries to change the actual value of your loop variable.

Comment: dont do arithmatic operations on $index...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `+ 1`. `++` always modifies the variable, and that *never* works well when you do that on a loop variable.

```
$index + 1
```

And this is the correct syntax for the `ng-repeat`. You don't need a `by $index`. `$index` is created automatically.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in quotation.items">
```

Comment: You're welcome. @entre, Why'd you add `by $index` back in? It was throwing errors for me, but I'm new to javascript.

Comment: Ok, I see now. I had left `track` in. Taking out `track` or adding `by $index` in both work.